# How to programmatically retrieve list of all pages in HippoCMS?

Tags: list, sitemap, hippocms

In HippoCMS, I've created Document Type and want to provide dynamic field that will list all available pages, just like when creating new page through Channel Manager in CMS (when clicked to Pages button, there is list of all pages available). I can retrieve the list by parsing sitemap.xml provided by *forge-sitemap-based-on-hst-configuration-feed*, but it seems like there must better way to do it. I couldn't find any information about it. Please, help me who can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out how to retrieve sitemap items (urls) programmatically (with relevant page titles).
1) Add property **hst:componentconfigurationid = hst:components/forge-sitemap-based-on-hst-configuration-feed** to 
*/hst:hst/hst:configurations/hst:default/hst:sitemap/sitemap.xml*
2) Create component that will handle request:

```
public class SitemapComponent extends CommonComponent{
  @Override
  public void doBeforeRender(final HstRequest request, final HstResponse response) throws HstComponentException {
    super.doBeforeRender(request, response);

    final Map<String, String> items = new HashMap<String, String>();

    List<HstSiteMapItem> siteMapItems = getHstSite(request).getSiteMap().getSiteMapItems();
    crawlSitemapItems(request, siteMapItems, items);

    request.setAttribute(REQUEST_ATTR_DOCUMENT, items);
  }

  public void crawlSitemapItems(HstRequest request, List<HstSiteMapItem> siteMapItems, Map<String, String> items) {
    HstRequestContext ctx = request.getRequestContext();

    for (HstSiteMapItem siteMapItem : siteMapItems) {
        if (siteMapItem.getPageTitle() != null) {
            HstLink link = ctx.getHstLinkCreator().create(siteMapItem, getMount(request));

            if (!link.getPath().isEmpty()) {
                int index = link.getPath().indexOf("/");
                if (index > -1) {
                    items.put(link.getPath(), siteMapItem.getPageTitle());
                }

                List<HstSiteMapItem> children = siteMapItem.getChildren();
                if (!children.isEmpty()) {
                    crawlSitemapItems(request, children, items);
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

3) Set **hst:componentclassname = com.test.cms.components.SitemapComponent** to required hst:component

Answer (score 0):

Hippo CMS is essentially a content based CMS. This means that while you may have a view of pages, the pages themselves don't exist as such. You can check the code in the sitemap plugin to see how its done, but basically you have to check all the documents to see if they are mapped and all the mappings to see if there are documents. You have to check both ways as mappings can be done on patterns and need not reference any documents at all. This is for the general case of course, your situation may be simpler.

Comment: I mean, I need to retrieve the list of available pages (paths), example: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43752378/cms.png)